# How to make a grid with 2 columns with different sizes?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

This is driving me crazy for several hours now.
I just want to define a GridLayout with 2 columns.
The first column should take 70% of the total width.
The second column should take the rest, 30%.
All the sample I could find out here are columns with equal size.
Furthermore, I wand the cell content to adjust to the cell sizes, not the other way around.

I may be wrong but I thought I understand that

> android:layout_columnWeight

is the way to govern the column width ?

So here is my code so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rowCount="5">
    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:text="@string/goals"
        fontPath="fonts/Ubuntu-Bold.ttf" />
    <ImageButton
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_settings_black_18dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:text="Stabiliser mon poinds à 90kg"
        android:id="@+id/objective1" />
    <Com.Syncfusion.Gauges.SfCircularGauge.SfCircularGauge
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_width="0sp"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/sfCircularGaugeGoal1Score" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:text="Manger plu sain"
        android:id="@+id/objective2" />
    <Com.Syncfusion.Gauges.SfCircularGauge.SfCircularGauge
                android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_width="0sp"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/sfCircularGaugeGoal2Score" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:text="Pratiquer des activités en famille régulièrement"
        android:id="@+id/objective3" />
    <Com.Syncfusion.Gauges.SfCircularGauge.SfCircularGauge
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_width="0sp"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/sfCircularGaugeGoal3Score" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:text="Augmenter mes revenus"
        android:id="@+id/objective4" />
    <Com.Syncfusion.Gauges.SfCircularGauge.SfCircularGauge
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_width="0sp"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/sfCircularGaugeGoal4Score" />
</GridLayout>
```

The result in the VS for Mac designer is:

[image]

But at runtime, I can't see the controls on each row on the left. Please note that the text is changed at runtime, and there's only one row with content.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Linear layout with weight and weight sum for it. It dynamically divides the screen according to ratio. what u want. Use below scatch to understand the pattern

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/tempo_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

      <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="10">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="7">

               <!--add 30% content here -->

           </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="3">

               <!--add 70% content here -->

           </LinearLayout>

      </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I could understand the pattern but a simple textview inside the 70% sized column is not visible at all.

Comment: This seems the way to go but, the second linear layout should be horizontal, right ? Doing so gives me a result that is not far away for what I'm looking for. Unfortunately, the top linear layout is not filling the parent space

Comment: I finally managed to to what I wanted with this technique. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answer, that LinearLayout is probably the way to go.

Here's how to do it with the GridLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rowCount="5">
    <TextView
        android:layout_columnWeight="7"
        android:text="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_columnWeight="3"
        android:text="2"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_columnWeight="7"
        android:text="3"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_columnWeight="3"
        android:text="4"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_columnWeight="7"
        android:text="5"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_columnWeight="3"
        android:text="6"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_columnWeight="7"
        android:text="7"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_columnWeight="3"
        android:text="8"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_columnWeight="7"
        android:text="9"/>
</GridLayout>
```

And here's how to do it with a LinearLayout:
(I edited the other answer, but it doesn't show because I don't have enough reputation)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!--add 70% content here -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!--add 30% content here -->
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: These changes alone have no effect.